# $_GET and $_POST doesn't work

Tags: php

I read all questions related to $_GET and $_POST. I didn't find a solution for my case. The code is very simple, it should be working, but I get empty field when using $_GET.
Here is my code :

```
DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Colors</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Project</h2>
<form method="get" action="display.php">
R:<input type="text" name="r" size="3"/> <p/>
G:<input type="text" name="g" size="3"/><p/>
B:<input type="text" name="b" size="3"/><p/>
<input type="submit" value ="Show me">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title>Colors</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Color Sampler </h2>
<?php
$r=$_GET['r'];
$g=$_GET['g'];
$b=$_GET['b'];
$rgb=$r . ',' . $g . ',' . $b;
?>
R:<?php echo $r; ?>
G:<?php echo $g; ?>
B:<?php echo $b; ?>
 <p/>
<div style ="width:150px;height:150px;
background-color:rgb(<?php echo $rgb;?>"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

and this is what I get:

```
Project 2 Color Sampler 
R: G: B:
```

so it is empty, like it doesn't see the values he needs to return.

What is wrong?

Comment: add `print_r($_GET);` an see what you get

Comment: Besides, what's those <p/> doing there?

Comment: Whats with the `<p/>`s

Comment: add also to your php `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` (for debugging)

Comment: I'll be captain obvious and ask - did you even fill in those boxes before submitting, and if yes, what does your URL say after the submission? Can you see the values there?

Comment: i hate waiting for the OP to answer the questions, the suspense is killing me!

Comment: for me its working fine and i got the values by using `print_r`, dont know whats wrong. and just a tip, if you are using the `size` attribute to limit the maximum value length to 3, the use `maxlength="3"`. and manually call your `display.php` by typing link on your browsers address bar like this `display.php?r=200&g=121&b=100` and see what happens

Comment: Why does title of the question refer to `$_POST`? Haven't you told us something about using POST method?

Comment: Maxim, you are new at stackoverflow, here is a secret: Next time you post, stay near and  answer our questions. Sometimes you get 90% of attention in the first 5 minutes. Then people go to other questions and don't come back.

Comment: hey, print_r doesn't work

Comment: thank's Sergio. I'm indeed new and it takes me some time to test all suggestions

Comment: when I add print_r, I get the same screen as before

Comment: did you put it in the php, you should at least get an empty "array()"

Comment: Did you insert values in the `<input fields>` before pressing submit? please share a live link if you can.

Comment: That works if I manually call php file. I get values like I want, but why I can't receive same result from html doc?

Comment: and I see next message Color Sampler 
R:200G:121B:100Array ( [r] => 200 [g] => 121 [b] => 100 )

Comment: Do you have a link to the page so we can test also?

Comment: Sergio, I put the values and I get this: Color Sampler 
R: G: B:

Comment: file is on localhost, not sure you can access to it

Comment: Dagon, I put it in php doc, and still have the same screen

Comment: this is going to be something silly i bet, well off to work

Comment: @MaximTelitsyn, in stackoverflow your can write with `@` to send a message to someones inbox. For example "@Sergio"

Comment: If it works when you change the url query, and the html is what you posted here. I see no error (except small things others wrote also about). Maybe it's in your computer. If you have a website, test it online.

Comment: Sergio, I'd like to share screen with you

Comment: You can post a photo here. Anyway if your code is like you posted here correct `DOCTYPE` to `<!DOCTYPE` on top of page, also change `<p/>` to `<p>&nbsp;</p>`. What do you mean with "size" in the input field?

Comment: @MaximTelitsyn in your address bar do you get something similar `display.php?r=6&g=6&b=6`

Comment: @MaximTelitsyn I tried your script as posted, and it worked fine for me, without any modifications.

Comment: @MaximTelitsyn If you're trying to run your script under `localhost`, chances are you've got something that's **not Kosher**. Try it **Live** on the WeeB and see; yes, I said **"WeeB"**. (*For those who remember*) ;)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can delete 'method="get"' from  cause it uses be default.
 Also, try to get params from $_REQUEST. Good luck!

Comment: bad idea *2, always be specific, never assume anything. as $_REQUEST. contains $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE this will just make it harder to find the iisue